# Continue the numbering of theorems in algorithm environments

Tags: numbering, algorithms, algorithmic, thmtools

I'm using the `thmtools` package to get theorem like environments where the theorem numbering is of the form SECTION.THEOREMNUMBER:

```
\declaretheorem[numberwithin = chapter]{theorem}
\declaretheorem[sibling = theorem, style = definition]{definition}
\declaretheorem[sibling = theorem, style = definition]{lemma}
```

Now I also want to include algorithms using the packages `algorithm` and `algpseudocode`. I've specified the first packaged via `\usepackage[section]{algorithm}`. However, the numbering now is only SECTION.ALGORITHMNUMBER. If there are theorems before an algorithm, they are ignored (i.e. the numbering is not continued). Phrased differently: The algorithms within a section are numbered independently of the theorems. How can I fix that?

Comment: Please add a minimal (non)working example, from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`